# Isometric Immersion of $S^1\to M$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

$M$ be any Riemannian manifold, and $S^1$ is a circle.
We can give Manifold structure to $C^\infty(S^1, M)$ modeled on nuclear frechet space.

Take $Imm(S^1, M):\{f\in C^\infty(S^1,M): f \text{ is an immersion} \}$.  This is open subset of $C^\infty(S^1,M)$ hence it is also a nuclear frechet manifold.

Consider set of all isomoetric immersion of $S^1\to M$, can we give some differentiable structure here.  Please provide the reference where people have already studied the isometric immersed loops over a manifold.

**Edit:**   Can we see  Set of isometric immersion as a manifold modeled over some Locally convex space.

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiable structure"?  If you work in a suitable category of generalised smooth spaces then you've already given it a smooth structure by embedding it in the loop space, so it inherits the ambient structure.

Comment: Edited..   Differentiable structure: I mean manifold structure.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at Peter W. Michor's "Manifolds of Differerentiable Mappings" and related work of his and his co-authors.  They have many articles on the arXiv that address questions of smooth structures of various kinds on spaces of smooth mappings.

Comment: You also might be interested in "A Kähler structure on the moduli space of isometric maps of a circle into Euclidean space" by 
John J. Millson and Brett Zombro, Inventiones, vol. 123 (1996)  Number 1, 35-59. They consider both smooth and Lipschitz settings. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case where $\dim M = 3$ is considered in Brylinski's book *Loop spaces, characteristic classes and geometric quantization* (I don't know where it originates, presumably there are references in the book if it doesn't originate there - I don't have a copy to hand).

The method given there ought to generalise.  Look at an isometric immersion, say $\alpha \colon S^1 \to M$.  A chart at $\alpha$ for the full loop space, $L M = C^\infty(S^1, M)$, has domain $\Gamma_{S^1}(\alpha^* T M)$.  So long as the chart map is chosen carefully (and I'm pretty sure it can be done so), the following should work.  As $\alpha$ is an immersion, we have a non-zero section $\alpha' \in \Gamma_{S^1}(\alpha^* T M)$.  The fibrewise orthogonal complement (in the induced metric from $T M$) of this defines a subbundle, say $E_\alpha$, of $\alpha^* T M$.  We take sections of this, $\Gamma_{S^1}(E_\alpha)$, and restrict the chart map to this.  The idea being that if $\beta$ is the image of a section $X$ then $\|\beta'\|^2 = \|\alpha'\|^2 + 2\langle \alpha', X \rangle + \| X\|^2$ and to first order, as $\langle \alpha', X \rangle = 0$ then this is $\|\alpha'\|^2 = 1$ (as $\alpha$ is an immersion).  To make this precise one would need to choose the original chart map very carefully, but as I said I don't think that would be difficult and the details should generalise from the 3-manifold case as given in Brylinski's book.

Comment: @Andew Stacey...   So if i understand correctly, You are trying to give manifold structure to set of all immersion....  

Comment: *Isometric* immersions.  By taking the orthogonal complement of the tangent vector in the chart domain, we don't disturb the isometric condition.


Answer (score 1):

Let $(M, g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, and $f \colon S^1 \to M$ a smooth immersion. The metric $f^* g$ on $S^1$ is flat, since $S^1$ is one-dimensional. Since the flat metric is unique up to diffeomorphism then, given any fixed metric $h$ on $S^1$, there exists a diffeomorphism $\varphi \colon S^1 \to S^1$ such that the pull-back $f^* g$ under $\varphi$ is $h$. In particular, given any immersion $f$, there exists a $\varphi$ such that $f \circ \varphi$ is an isometry. As such, the space of isometric immersions may be identified with the quotient of the space of smooth immersions by isometric diffeomorphisms (i.e. rotations) of $S^1$.

Comment: But how is this relevant to the question?

Comment: All I am saying is that I believe any immersion is isometric, therefore the space of isometric immersions has the same differentiable structure, etc as the space of immersions. 

Comment: If i am not making mistake then, take $f:S^1\subset \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ $f(e^{i\theta))= \frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}$... This is immersion but not isometry.
All metric are induced from $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Arch has a point. This means that given any smooth immersion $f$ of $S^1$, you can find a diffeomorphism $\phi$ of $S^1$ such that $f\circ \phi$ is isometric with respect to the standard metric on $S^1$. Using this fact, you should be able to define the space of isometric immersions of $S^1$ with the standard metric into a manifold as a quotient of the space of all smooth immersions.

Comment: To clarify, as Prof. Yang points out, I was implicitly allowing myself to reparametrise the $S^1$. 

Comment: Arch, how about if you edit your answer and provide all the details?

Comment: Ok, I have tried to do this. I would appreciate if you could check, as I am not completely sure about the isotropy group. 

Comment: Oy. My apologies. Everything I've said is wrong. If you fix a metric on the circle, then it implies a length of the circle. On the other hand, if you take an arbitrary immersion of the circle into $M$, then the induced metric implies another length that is not necessarily equal to the first length. So the space of isometric immersions is *not* a quotient of the space of all smooth immersions.

Comment: You can, however, use instead the space of immersions where the induced length is equal to the given length of the circle (presumably $2\pi$). I believe that the space of isometric immersions can be identified roughly as the quotient of smooth immersions with induced length equal to $2\pi$ by the space of diffeomorphisms of the circle homotopic to the identity that fix a distinguished point on the circle.

Comment: For this to answer the question, you need to either know that this quotient is a smooth manifold or to work in a category of generalised smooth spaces where quotients are allowed.  The former is not obvious to me - maybe it is to you and Deane!.  If the latter, then all of the categories that I know of are also closed under taking subobjects, in which case the space of immersions gets a natural smooth structure from the ambient loop space with no need for taking quotients.

Comment: Andrew, I agree that what I'm saying does not answer the question.

Comment: I am not an expert on the smooth structures on the quotients, which is why I initially wanted to post a comment rather than an answer. Also, in the edited answer that I gave above, the flat metric on $S^1$ is, I guess, unique up to a scale and a diffeomorphism, rather than just a diffeomorphism. However, if one also quotients by the scale as well as rotations, doesn't this give the isometric immersions as a quotient of the space of all smooth immersions? 

Comment: Arch, what does "quotient by the scale" mean?

Comment: In your earlier comment, you were worried that the length with respect to the induced metric may not coincide with the length from the fixed metric on $S^1$. I am just wondering whether we may absorb the difference in length into the diffeomorphism $\varphi$. In particular, we could take the $\varphi$ from before and compose with a homothety that takes care of the scaling of the length. 

Comment: Homothety of what? The circle? What's a homothety of a circle?

Comment: All I mean is the following. Suppose we have a fixed metric, $h$, on $S^1$ and that the length of the $S^1$ with respect to this metric is $2\pi$, say. I now use the immersion to define a new metric on $S^1$, $f^* g$, with respect to which the length of the $S^1$ is $2 \pi \lambda^2$, say, for some $\lambda > 0$. We would then be able to find $\varphi \colon S^1 \to S^1$ such that $\varphi^* f^* g$ equals $\lambda h$. This would mean that, to go from immersions to isometric immersions, I would need to quotient by $S^1 \times \mathrm{positive reals}$. 

Comment: If you want to quotient by positive reals, then you have to have a group action of the positive reals on the space of all smooth immersions of the circle into the Riemannian manifold. What is this group action?

Comment: Ah, ok, I get your point now. Yes, you're right. Sorry for confusing matters.

Comment: No problem. Just keep at it.

Comment: @Arch Stanton, and @Deane Yang....  Where the proof is wrong... I can't see...   If we fix a metric of $h$ on $S^1$... then there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: S^1\to S^1$ such that induced metric from some immersion $f^*g$ is same as $h$ via $\phi$. Notation is same as in answer.

Comment: Dear Pradip Mishra. Pulling back the induced metric with $\varphi$ will not change the induced length of length of the circle, i.e. the length of the $S^1$ with the metric $f^* g$ is the same as that with the metric $\varphi^* f^* g$. If this is not the same as the length of the circle with the metric $h$, then $\varphi^* f^* g$ and $h$ cannot be the same metric. I hope this helps.